# Keeping track of index in an editable listview populated by observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, observablecollection

As a WPF newbie, I'm kindof going round in circles trying to work with observable collections.

So here's what i'm trying to do using the MVVM pattern. 
I have a form in which I am trying to enter, say, skill sets of a person.

The following is my UI layout and hopefully this will also give you an idea of what my datacontext for each view is

```
Main Window
     SubScreen
        TextBlk(not a part of the user Control below)
        ListView
            UserControl(added to listview Only upon a button click)
                 ComboBox (ItemSource = SkillsList eg: C,C++, C# etc)
                 TxtBox (Binding TotalExperience... a number)
                 Radion Buttons (Bound to skillLevel property eg: Beginner, Expert etc)
        Button (Command = Add new skill set row => repeat the usercontrol in a new list view row)
```

The user Control is my observable collection.

How do I make sure the usercontrol is populated correctly? How do I keep track of which row of the listView I am working on (i.e: adding or editing)? Can I save the collection as a whole for a particular person? All this I am trying to do in the View model...no code behind file.

Apologies if the questions are naive. But the more I read up the more confused I get. Would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: A real simple way to keep track of what row you're working on is to bind a value on your viewmodel to SelectedIndex of the listview.  You can also bind to the value itself and avoid the index issue completely (my recommendation).  Without seeing code I cannot provide specifics, but something along the lines of SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentWorkItem}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is pretty huge to answer. Read this article it shows a good example of a xml only set up

[WPF/MVVM Quick Start Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial)

After you run through the first link it would be worth looking here too

[Implementing the MVVM Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx)

Pay particular attention to the INotifyPropertyChanged example. This is how you keep track of which record you are working on.

You will have a model which is passed around, it contains all fields you create in it including the ID if necessary.

Also if you are trying for no code behind then also pay attention to the Commands.

Hope this helps.